# Export Visual Studio 2012 to 2010 sln format

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

My teacher is complaining that he can't read the VS2012 format on his VS2010 environment. I looked around in settings and so on but couldn't find anything. How can I give the project in an VS2010 readable format to my teacher?

Comment: Have you tried opening the .sln file in a text editor and changing the 11.00 to a 10.00?  [I don't think there are any major changes in the format that would affect a simple project--I could be wrong, but it can't hurt to try.]  Otherwise, just create a new Solution and add the projects to it.

Comment: that not solove the framework problem 4.5 to 4

Comment: Framework can be easily changed in the `Project Properties` under the `Application` tab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming this is not a terribly complex project (I'm making that assumption since there is a teacher involved), the easiest approach may be just to re-create the project in Visual Studio 2010.

Fire up VS2010, add your files, make any necessary changes to settings, and save.

You will need VS2010 no matter what approach you take.  Even if you convert the project file by other means, it would be very wise to test it before handing it in again.  The Express edition is free.

Comment: Thank u for the response. The teacher claims "you know u can add both projects in the same solution"

Comment: Maybe so (never saw a reason to try that), but there is really no reason to have two versions of the same project file.  I can see no benefit in doing that.

Answer (score 12):

### Modifying sln manually

1. Backup your project folder (copy/paste to another location, like a folder called "backups")
2. Open sln file on wordpad
3. Change the "header" of opened sln to below (the first lines that matches mentioned lines below, except by version number/name):

   ```
   Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
   # Visual Studio 2010
   ```

I'll see if there is a way to do it in project options...

Comment: There are additional XML nodes in VS2012 that were not in VS2010.  Not sure how VS2010 handles it if it finds these nodes.

Comment: Well, I recommend just to try, because it is easy to do... But also it is better to backup entire folder instead of only the sln file (I edited answer)...

Comment: Didn't work for me. I found that you have to create the project in VS 2010 SP1 first, then you can open it in VS 2012. If you create the project in VS 2012 first, you then cannot open in in VS 2010 SP1. At least, that is my experience.

Comment: Only works if target framework is changed to 4.0 in the project properties.

Answer (score 11):

If the VS2010 installation has SP1 installed, then it should be able to read the VS2012 solution file.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to do it is to right click on the source code, open it with a program such as notepad, then save that on to a USB stick. When you go to class, copy and paste this into Visual Studio 2010 and viola.