# Loading Visual Studio 12 project in Visual Studio 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Export Visual Studio 2012 to 2010 sln format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356855/export-visual-studio-2012-to-2010-sln-format)

I recently made the switch to VS12.  Unfortunately my computer crashed the other day and while it's in the shop I'm on a machine without a copy of VS12. When I try to load any Class Library or Console Application project which was created in VS12 it say's incompatible.

Are there any updates to windows or changes I can make to the project file to get it to load in visual studio 2010?

I've installed .net 4.5 but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Depends on the type of project, what kind have you created?

Comment: Worst case scenario you could try installing one of the express 2010 editions until your computer is fixed (assuming your features are supported).